# How to find the minimum value of multiple function in the chi-square distribution?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I got a multiple function in the following way：

```
M = G = c = 1;

Ωϕ = M^(1/2)/(r^(3/2) + a M^(1/2));
Ωr = Ωϕ (1 - (6 M)/r + (8 a M^(1/2))/
     r^(3/2) - (3 a^2)/r^2);
Ωθ = Ωϕ (1 - (4 a M^(1/2))/r^(
     3/2) + (3 a^2)/r^2);

pre1 = 1*MachinePrecision;

c = SetPrecision[3.0 10^8 , pre1];
G = SetPrecision[6.67259 10^-11 , pre1];

Ms = SetPrecision[1.989 10^30, pre1];
MMs = M1  Ms;
νϕ[a_, r_, M1_] = 
  1/(2 Pi) c^3/(G  MMs) Sqrt[Ωϕ];
νr[a_, r_, M1_] = 1/(2 Pi) c^3/(G  MMs) Sqrt[Ωr];
νθ[a_, r_, M1_] = 
  1/(2 Pi) c^3/(G  MMs) Sqrt[Ωθ];

νL[a_, r_, M1_] = νϕ[a, r, M1] - νr[a, r, M1];
νC[a_, r_, M1_] = νϕ[a, r, M1] - νθ[a, r, M1];
νU[a_, r_, M1_] = νϕ[a, r, M1];
ν1U = 441;
ν1L = 298;
ν1C = 17.3;
M1L1 = 63/10;
σ1U = 2;
σ1L = 4;
σ1C = 0.1;
σ1M = 27/100;
χ[a_, r_, 
  M1_] := (νU[a, r, M1] - ν1U)^2/σ1U^2 + (νL[a, r, 
     M1] - ν1L)^2/σ1L^2 + (νC[a, r, 
     M1] - ν1C)^2/σ1C^2
```

Next I want to solve the minimum value of
`χ[a, r, M1]`
by using FindMinimum. But I can't get the value I want.
PS：
In the literature [arXiv:1312.2228], the minimum value of

```
χ[a, r, M1]
```

is located in A = 0.286 and M1 = 5.3.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! First of all, you are not actually looking to find a minimum of multiple, function, but instead a minimum of _one_ function with multiple variables. Second, you can use [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) to find a minimum. Third, what is the $r$ corresponding to the minimum? I couldn't have found ...

Comment: it mentioned in the paper. Lastly, it is very likely you have some error in the code or in the equations. For example, `NMinimize[{χ[a, r, M1], r > 5, 0.2 < a < 0.4, 5 < M1 < 5.5}, {a, r, M1}]` which is bounded to give best `a` and `M1` where you expect it gives `{24937.6, {a -> 0.4, r -> 22.4791, M1 -> 5.5}}`.

Comment: why do you square root the Omega frequencies in the formulas to get the Nu frequencies? That does not stand in the formulas in the literature...